# jwks-rsa error when getting signing keys - JwksError: Forbidden

Tags: node.js, jwt

I'm trying to validate a JWT dynamically using `jsonwebtoken` and `jwks-rsa` and I'm getting a forbidden error. The example I'm using is basically [straight from the docs](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback).

```
    const client = jwksClient({
        jwksUri: 'https://a-site/.well-known/jwks.json'
    });

    function getKey(header, callback){
        client.getSigningKey(header.kid, function(err, key) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err); // This returns "JwksError: Forbidden"
            }
            var signingKey = key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey;
            callback(null, signingKey);
        });
    }
    const opts = {
        audience: 'aud value',
        issuer: "iss value"
    };

    return jwt.verify(token, getKey, opts, (err, decoded) => {
        return decoded;
    });
```

I can hit the URI in my browser and see the keys, but the error message doesn't give me much to go on, it simply reads `JwksError: Forbidden`. Any suggestions what the cause may be? I'm relatively new to JWT's and I'm not clear what part of this I'd be 'forbidden' from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my instance of this error! The openId issuer required (but didn't mention!) a `user-agent` header to be set. In my case, this could have any value, as long as it was present in the header, so the following alteration to the above solved my issue.

```
const client = jwksClient({
  jwksUri,
  requestHeaders: {
    'user-agent': 'some-user-agent'
  }
});
```

Full working example:

```
const client = jwksClient({
  jwksUri,
  requestHeaders: {
    'user-agent': 'some-user-agent'
  }
});

function getKey(header, callback){
    client.getSigningKey(header.kid, function(err, key) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err); // This no longer returns an error
        }
        var signingKey = key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey;
        callback(null, signingKey);
    });
}
const opts = {
    audience: 'aud value',
    issuer: "iss value"
};

return jwt.verify(token, getKey, opts, (err, decoded) => {
    return decoded; // Returns the successfully decoded key!
});
```